# Reached nested IF limit in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Does anyone know a way to shorten this Excel formula, as I have reached the nested "IF" limit?

```
=IF(Sheet!$G$2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$H2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",
 IF(Sheet!$I2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$J2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",
 IF(Sheet!$K2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$L2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",
 IF(Sheet!$M2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$N2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",
 IF(Sheet!$O2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$P2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",
 IF(Sheet!$Q2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$R2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",""))))))))))))
```

Comment: Without going evaluating your equation, when I have encountered the same problem I figure out how to move part of the analysis to another cell, then just make an IF statement that applies to that cell.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** My answer, below, was approached the way you would with digital logic circuits, where conditions are evaluated in parallel.  In that case, you need to explicitly provide for every condition.  That was total over-kill here; way more complicated than necessary.

The approaches shown in thilina R's answer take advantage of the fact that Excel evaluates formulas and ranges in sequence, so Excel is already doing most of the work of limiting possible conditions similar to the nested IFs in the question.

We both came up with the OR logic shown as my last approach, below.  I'll leave this answer for whatever educational or novelty value it might provide.  But thilina R's answer contains the practical solutions, and my vote is Method 1: HLOOKUP.

---

It isn't clear whether you might be using a formula that is more restrictive than necessary.  I'll use a little shorthand notation here to simplify discussion.  I'll leave out the sheetnames, and refer to the equality tests in this way:  If it's true that `G2=I2`, I'll just call it `G2`.  If it's false that G2=I2, I'll call it `Not-G2`.  With this shorthand, your nested IFs can be expressed like this:

```
    G2 
or: H2 and Not-G2
or: I2 and Not-G2 and Not-H2
or: J2 and Not-G2 and Not-H2 and Not-I2
etc.
```

If that's the rules you need, you can do it with one IF and all of that AND and OR logic.  It would look like this in shorthand:

```
=IF(OR(G2,AND(H2,Not-G2),AND(I2,Not-G2,Not-H2),...),"Y","")
```

Filling in the actual formula would look like this:

```
=IF(OR(Sheet!$G$2=Sheet1!I2,
       AND(Sheet!$H2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$I2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$J2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$K2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$L2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$M2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$N2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2,Sheet!$M2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$O2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2,Sheet!$M2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$N2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$P2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2,Sheet!$M2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$N2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$O2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$Q2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2,Sheet!$M2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$N2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$O2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$P2<>Sheet1!I2),
       AND(Sheet!$R2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$G$2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$J2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2<>heet1!I2,Sheet!$M2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$N2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$O2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$P2<>Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$Q2<>Sheet1!I2)),"Y","")
```

(I can't guarantee a typo didn't slip in there).  Formulas that long are very difficult to enter and maintain.  It can be helpful to use helper cells for pieces of the formula.

**If that isn't actually the rules you need, here are a few simpler cases:**

- If you don't need that sequence, and only care that any one, and only one, cell is equal to I2, here's a way to do the same logic with one IF:

  `=IF((Sheet!$G$2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$H2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$I2=Sheet1!I2)+
      (Sheet!$J2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$K2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$L2=Sheet1!I2)+
      (Sheet!$M2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$N2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$O2=Sheet1!I2)+
      (Sheet!$P2=Sheet1!I2)+(Sheet!$Q2=Sheet1!I2)+
      (Sheet!$R2=Sheet1!I2)=1,"Y","")`

  Each set of parentheses contains one of your tests.  If the equality is true, it produces a value of `1`,  If not true, the value will be `0`.  That's how Excel represents true and false.

  The results of all of these tests are added up.  If the sum is `1`, it means that one and only one of the tests was true.
- If, in reality, you only care if at least one of those cases is true, you could use a simple OR:

  `=IF(OR(Sheet!$G$2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$H2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$I2=Sheet1!I2,
         Sheet!$J2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$K2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$L2=Sheet1!I2,
         Sheet!$M2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$N2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$O2=Sheet1!I2,
         Sheet!$P2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$Q2=Sheet1!I2,Sheet!$R2=Sheet1!I2),"Y","")`

Note that I've added line breaks and extra spaces within all of the formulas so that the logic is easier to see.  If you want to copy and paste, you will need to remove those.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to know if any of the cells `G2:R2` in one sheet has the same value as cell `I2` on a different sheet.

There are several ways to do it. The easiest way that comes to mind is this since the values you are checking are in a continuous range:

**Method 1: HLOOKUP/VLOOKUP**

```
=IF(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(Sheet1!I2,Sheet!G2:R2,1,FALSE)),"","Y")
```

This uses looks up the value in cell `I2` on one sheet and checks if it is in the other sheet in the range `G2:R2`. If the `HLOOKUP` finds at least one value in the range `G2:R2` that matches cell `I2` in the other sheet, it returns `Y` or otherwise doesn't return a value.

I have used `HLOOKUP` since the range provided was a horizontal range. If the range is a vertical range, you can use `VLOOKUP` instead.

If the values are *not* in a continuous range for any reason, you can use the other 2 methods below.

Here is another way:

**Method 2: CONCATENATE**

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(Sheet1!I2,CONCATENATE(Sheet!G2,Sheet!H2,Sheet!I2,Sheet!J2,Sheet!K2,Sheet!L2,Sheet!M2,Sheet!N2,Sheet!O2,Sheet!P2,Sheet!Q2,Sheet!R2))),"","Y")
```

This basically makes a big string of all the values in the cells `G2:R2` and checks if the value in cell `I2` of the other sheet is in that. If it is, it returns `Y` otherwise it doesn't return a value.

Note that since this method makes a big string out of all the data in the range of cells you need to look up, depending on the type of data in those cells, it could return `Y` incorrectly. For example: If `Sheet1!I2` has the value `123` and `Sheet!G2` has the value `12` and `Sheet!H2` has the value `34`, this method will still show `Y` since the "big string" will contain "1234..." and the value `123` will be in this string.

Yet another way to do this is:

**Method 3: Boolean operator  - OR**

*[@fixer1234 had mentioned this first]*

```
=IF(OR((Sheet!G2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!H2=Sheet1!I2),(Sheet!I2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!J2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!K2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!L2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!M2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!N2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!O2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!P2=Sheet1!I2), (Sheet!Q2=Sheet!I2), (Sheet!R2=Sheet1!I2) ),"Y","")
```

This uses the boolean operator `OR` to check if any of the values in the range `G2:R2` are in the cell `I2` on the other sheet. If the boolean operator finds at least one value that matches cell `I2` in the other sheet, it returns `Y` or otherwise doesn't return a value.

**Method 4: Spread out the formula**

1. If you want to just only use `IF` conditions (for some reason I can't imagine), you can spread out the `IF` conditions into multiple cells and then use the result of those cells to determine the final result. For example: you could have a few of the `IF` conditions in one cell and you can use the result of this in another cell along with the a few more `IF` conditions and so on.

You could have the following in cell `A1` of a sheet:

```
=IF(Sheet!$G$2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$H2=Sheet1!I2,"Y", IF(Sheet!$I2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$J2=Sheet1!I2,"Y", IF(Sheet!$K2=Sheet1!I2,"Y","")))))
```

And then, you could have the following in cell `A2` of a sheet:

```
=IF(A1="Y", "Y", IF(Sheet!$L2=Sheet1!I2,"Y", IF(Sheet!$M2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$N2=Sheet1!I2,"Y", ""))))
```

Finally, you could have the following in cell `A3` of a sheet:

```
=IF(A2="Y","Y",IF(Sheet!$O2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$P2=Sheet1!I2,"Y", IF(Sheet!$Q2=Sheet1!I2,"Y",IF(Sheet!$R2=Sheet1!I2,"Y","")))))
```

**Method 5: VBA**

Use VBA if you are comfortable with it to create a custom user defined function in which you can have as many nested `If` statements.

***Note: The output of both these formulas is the same as the formula that you provided.***

Comment: You stole my OR!  Actually, that one isn't guaranteed to give the same result as the OP's nested IFs.  My first reaction to your other two was that they aren't guaranteed to be the same, but I think you're right.  The HLOOKUP and FIND both look for the first match in the given order, which mimics the action of the nested IFs.  So I believe your method 1 is the clear winner.

Comment: Oops. I also just noticed that. I was trying out different things and didn't realize it was there in your answer! I will update mine.

Comment: Excel evaluates the OR formula in the order written, so I think you're right on that one, too.  Looks like I did some over-thinking on my answer (or under-thinking?).  Your answer is better.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the answer with a few more methods as well. I think you were trying to explain the process to the OP in a different way which is what may have lead to that :)